# How to disable Morgan (request logger) during unit test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs

I use Morgan (default express generator request logger), and I'm trying to disable it during unit testing.

Currently I'm using the default configuration, which loads Morgan in `app.js`

```
const logger = require('morgan');
...
const app = express();
...
app.use(logger('dev'));
```

I tried moving the code to `bin/www` (which imports the express app and starts the server), but it wouldn't work...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [skip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan#skip) option of `morgan` like this:

```js
const logger = require('morgan');
const app = express();
app.use(logger('dev', { skip: (req, res) => process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' }));
```

When you run the unit test, the `process.env.NODE_ENV` will be set to 'test'. See [Environment Variables](https://jestjs.io/docs/27.x/environment-variables)

> **NODE_ENV** - Set to 'test' if it's not already set to something else.

Comment: Worked flawlessly! Thanks!

Comment: Another option would be to not `use` the logger when the environment is test.